# HandlebarsJS How to get random values from JSON

Tags: json, handlebars.js

Is there a way to get random values from a JSON file? My JSON contains a lot of content based on same musical artist, so I wanted to display data more randomly and add a show more button afterwards...

so my JSON looks something like this:

```
[
  data: [{
     "name" : "rihanna",
     "song" : "pour it up"
     },
     {
      "name" : "rihanna"
      "song" : "diamonds"
     },
     {
      "name" : "ladygaga"
      "song" : "lovegame"
     },
     {
      "name" : "ladygaga"
      "song" : "lovegame"
     },
     {
      "name" : "ladygaga"
      "song" : "pokerface"
     },
     {
      "name" : "ladygaga"
      "song" : "alejandro"
     },
     {
      "name" : "fergie"
      "song" : "fergalicious"
     },
     {
      "name" : "fergie"
      "song" : "clumsy"
     },
     etc etc
```

So, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * jsonObject.length);
var rData = jsonObject[random];
```

P.S. : Where jsonObject ist your data property.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can acheive it. **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AVP1CqKbtCMeUOxOB5M?p=preview)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('button').on('click', function() {
        getRandom();
        var html = template(context);
        $('#artistlist').html(html);
    });

    var source = $("#entry-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

    var musicArray = [{
        "name": "rihanna",
        "song": "pour it up"
    }, {
        "name": "rihanna",
        "song": "diamonds"
    }, {
        "name": "ladygaga",
        "song": "lovegame"
    }, {
        "name": "ladygaga",
        "song": "lovegame"
    }, {
        "name": "ladygaga",
        "song": "pokerface"
    }, {
        "name": "ladygaga",
        "song": "alejandro"
    }, {
        "name": "fergie",
        "song": "fergalicious"
    }, {
        "name": "fergie",
        "song": "clumsy"
    }];


    var context = {
        music: []
    };

    var musicClone = $.extend(true, [], musicArray);

    function getRandom() {
        var i = 2;
        while (i-- && musicClone.length >= 1) {
            var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * musicClone.length);
            var data = musicClone[random];
            context.music.push(data);
            musicClone.splice(random, 1);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: thats very nice!! ok so do I have to add it in a register helper? If so, how do I fetch the json in a register helper?

Comment: No need for register helper.